# Check that triangle is right?

Tags: c, algorithm, geometry, computational-geometry

I'm trying to check if a triangle is a right triangle in C language. `a`, `b` and `c` are lengths of sides of some triangle.

```
int is_right_triangle(int a, int b, int c)
{
    return (a * a + b * b == c * c || a * a + c * c == b * b || b * b + c * c == a * a);
}
```

How I can avoid an integer overflow in sum and multiplication? Assume that we don't have a `long long` type.

Comment: The only way to avoid integer overflow is not having really big triangles. But for overflowing the long type you need really big triangles. What is the size range of your triangles ?

Comment: @MichaelWalz: "big" is relative. If the sides are measured in femtometers, the calculation will overflow for tiny triangles. Especially if `INT_MAX == 32767`.

Comment: @EOF, you apparently have some concept of "big" and "small" as a triangle of Venus - Earth - Mars is very small in light years :-)

Comment: You must create your own type if you cannot use longer type, and create your own calculation functions.

Comment: @Morovaille or, maybe, this algorithm is not the most suitable for the problem.

Comment: Starting with `(unsigned int a,unsigned int b, unsigned int c)` would be a good starting point.

Comment: @EOF that is true, we do not know the context...

Comment: Does calcuation of these triangles involve relatavistic effects or quantum mechanics?  If not, I don't see the problem...?

Comment: You could test if a, b and c are large and if yes, then divide them some value before doing the comparison; just a rough idea that needs to be refined. You also should consider not comparing for strict equality but compare if the difference is close to zero (also needs to be refined). Some context about what kind of triangles we are talking about would be helpful.

Comment: Or maybe `a * a  == abs(c *c - b*b)`. Correct me if I am wrong, I believe the subtraction is less likely is to overflow.

Comment: The concept of size doesn't exist when programming, only the concept of accuracy. You can measure the triangle in meters, nanometers or kilometers, whatever. (Study engineering notation of numbers) Then decide how many digits of accuracy you need, simple as that.

Comment: Also when picking data types, use common sense. Are there triangles with negative length sides? If not, why do you allow them for?

Comment: you're computing `a*a`, `b*b`, `c*c` and their sums again and again which is very inefficient. sort the edges and calculate their square only once

Comment: @Lundin I suppose it's an artificial trick to ensure an additional bit for calculating the sum: `(unsigned)a+b` cannot overflow if `a` and `b` are positive and of `int` type. Because this is such an artificial problem to solve (in real world, just use `int64_t` or `bigint`).

Comment: Without loss of generality, assume a ≤ b ≤ c

Answer (score 2):

**Improved(optimized) version**

1. Find the largest side and smallest side. (Without loss of generality, let's call them C and A). And B is the third side
2. Now C<sup>2</sup> - A<sup>2</sup> = B<sup>2</sup> for right angled triangle. i.e. (C+A)*(C-A)=B<sup>2</sup>, calculate unsigned_sum=C+A and unsigned_diff=C-A (unsigned int is guaranteed to not overflow for sum of `int`)
3. Divide sum, diff and B with the gcd of sum and diff. If it doesn't divide B, it is not a right angled triangle. If it does, sum and diff would be perfect square if triangle is right.
4. Find integer square root of sum and diff. If the product of roots is equal to B, triangle is right.

```
int is_right_triangle(int a, int b, int c)
{
  unsigned int sum, diff;
  int f = 2;  /* factor */
  unsigned int hcf, irts, irtd;

  /* sort */
  if(b > c) swap(&b, &c);
  if(a > b) swap(&a, &b);
  if(b > c) swap(&b, &c);

  sum = c;
  diff = c;
  sum += a;
  diff -= a;

  hcf = gcd(sum, diff);
  if(b % hcf != 0) return 0;
  sum /= hcf;
  diff /= hcf;
  b /= hcf;

  irts = isqrt(sum);
  if(irts * irts != sum || b % irts != 0) return 0;
  b /= irts;
  irtd = isqrt(diff);
  if(irtd * irtd != diff || b % irtd != 0) return 0;
  b /= irtd;

  return b == 1;
}
```

You can find the algorithm for `isqrt` @ [Methods_of_computing_square_roots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots#Example_2) or use binary search method.

```
#define NEXT(n, i)  (((n) + (i)/(n)) >> 1)  

unsigned int isqrt(int number) {  
  unsigned int n  = 1;  
  unsigned int n1 = NEXT(n, number);  

  while(abs(n1 - n) > 1) {  
    n  = n1;  
    n1 = NEXT(n, number);  
  }  
  while(n1*n1 > number)  
    n1--;  
  return n1;  
}
```

<sup>`isqrt` copied without change from [codecodex](http://www.codecodex.com/wiki/Calculate_an_integer_square_root)</sup>

---

**Old Answer**

1. Find the largest side and smallest side. (Without loss of generality, let's call them C and A). And B is the third side
2. Now C<sup>2</sup> - A<sup>2</sup> = B<sup>2</sup> for right angled triangle. i.e. (C+A)*(C-A)=B<sup>2</sup>, calculate unsigned_sum=C+A and unsigned_diff=C-A (unsigned int is guaranteed to not overflow for sum of `int`)
3. Gather the prime factors of unsigned_sum and unsigned_diff. If they are not multiple of 2, it is not right angled. If factors are multiple of 2, keep dividing copy_of_B = B, once with pair of prime factors seen. (Check up to fac*fac < max(unsigned_sum, unsigned_dif), if fac divides either, try dividing with other also)
4. If B = 1 at end, the triangle was right angled, else it is not.

```
int is_right_triangle(int a, int b, int c)
{
  unsigned int sum, diff;
  int f = 2;  /* factor */

  /* sort */
  if(b > c) swap(&b, &c);
  if(a > b) swap(&a, &b);
  if(b > c) swap(&b, &c);

  sum = c;
  diff = c;
  sum += a;
  diff -= a;

  while(f * f <= sum || f * f <= diff) {
    int count = 0;
    while(sum % f == 0) { sum /= f; ++count; }
    while(diff % f == 0) { diff /= f; ++count; }
    if(count % 2 == 1) return 0;
    while(count != 0) {
      b /= f;
      count -= 2;
    }
    ++f;  /* f = (f == 2 ? 3 : f + 2); */
  }
  return b == 1;
}
```

**Optimizations**
1. As mentioned in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36623053/check-that-triangle-is-right/36623713#comment60843913_36623713), you can divide unsigned_sum, unsigned_diff and b with gcd(unsigned_sum, unsigned_diff) and can handle unsigned_sum and unsigned_diff separately.
2. In the loop if you can check at any point that product of `sum` and `diff` (and square of b) is guaranteed to not overflow you can check for `sum * diff == (unsigned)b * b` and break accordingly.

Comment: `unsigned int` doesn't overflow, but it is reduced modulo the maximum number it can represent + 1.

Comment: Sounds intersting, but I'm quite getting it. Could you elaborate a bit ?

Comment: For sum of `int`s it doesn't if written as `u = a; u += b;` or `u = 0U + a + b;`

Comment: `sum += a;` can be less than the mathematical sum of `c` and `a`, in which case your algorithm fails.

Comment: @EOF Can you please explain how. Or give me **any** values for which this fails.

Comment: `c == UINT_MAX`, will result in `sum == a - 1`.

Comment: [Finding the prime factors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization) of `unsigned_sum` and `unsigned_diff` is not quite an easy task (if you want to complete it in reasonable time) and it's probably not worth it for the problem at hand. However, the idea can be refined using the [greatest common divisor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor) (it can be computed easily).

Comment: @MohitJain You have an interesting idea, looking at prime factors brilliant,  that greatly reduces the width of the integer required for  the computation. At worst you need one extra bit to handle addition instead of n bits to handle multiplication. And while your code can fail according to the Standard, you get my upvote.

Comment: `while(sum % f == 0) ++count;` is wrong, it leads to an infinite loop. Same for the following line. And even fixing this, I'm not sure this approach works. I can't check it further now, but I'm not convinced. Hopefully tonight I have some time.

Comment: Thanks a lot @FabiTurati for pointing. I fixed it. The code is untested and I present it just as an idea.

Comment: @MohitJain: I find your accusation of UB insulting. Where is it specified that `UINT_MAX > INT_MAX`?

Comment: Hi @EOF I am sorry if you felt that way(will delete the comment). If I don't get pedantic, `sizeof(int) = sizeof(unsigned int)` and `UINT_MAX >= 2 * INT_MAX`. If I get pedantic, I would try to dig the specs if you want.

Comment: @MohitJain: `sizeof()` is a red herring. Integer types are permitted to contain padding-bits.

Comment: @MohitJain C Standard permits `UINT_MAX == INT_MAX`. See: *9899:201x 6.2.6.2. p2*

Answer (score 2):

For all right triangles with integer sides a, b & c, there is always a pair of integers (m, n), such that;

```
g = gcd(a, gcd(b, c)); // greatest common divisor of a, b, c

baseA = a / g;
baseB = b / g;
baseC = c / g;

baseA = m * m - n * n;
baseB = 2 * m * n;
baseC = m * m + n * n;
```

Keeping this in mind ([see primitive Pythagorean triples on this page](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RightTriangle.html)), you can decompose `(baseB / 2)` (`baseB` being the even integer) to its factors and then check the factor pairs `(m, n)` (I'm afraid, this must be brute force) whether they satisfy the above conditions for `baseA` and `baseC` as well.

I think, this procedure will take care of overflow issue and assert that any intermediate step of computation will **never exceed the longest side** of the triangle; "c" in this case.

edit: @anatolyg is right. a, b & c are to be divided into their greatest common divisor, g; however, this correction still does not violate the acceptance of the solution, for down scaling all three integers will indeed help to assert the non-overflow constraint.

Last edit: I think the code below works (tested to the 32 bits integer limit & compiled with gcc).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//  linked list definition for the set of divisors
struct divisorSet {
    int divisor;
    struct divisorSet *next;
};

//  swaps two integers
void swap(int *a, int *b) {
    int t;

    t = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = t;

    return;
}

//  computes the greatest common divisor
int gcd(int a, int b) {
    int t;

    if (a < b) {
        swap(&a, &b);
    }

    while (b) {
        t = a % b;
        a = b;
        b = t;
    }

    return (a);
}

//  sorts a, b & c as follows:
//  a < c
//  b is the even integer regardless of its magnitude
int sort(int *a, int *b, int *c) {
    int oneEven;

    oneEven = 0;

    if (*b % 2) {
        if (*a % 2) {
            if (*c % 2) {
                oneEven = 1;
            }
            else {
                swap(b, c);
            }
        }
        else {
            swap(a, b);
        }
    }

    if (*a > *c) {
        swap(a, c);
    }

    return (oneEven);
}

//  creates the divisor set as linked list
struct divisorSet *createDivisorSet(int b) {
    struct divisorSet *dSet, *dTmp, *dBase;
    int l, i, k;

    k = sizeof(struct divisorSet);
    l = b / 2;
    dBase = malloc(k);
    dSet = dBase;
    i = 1;
    dSet->divisor = i;

    while (i++ < l) {
        if (!(b % i)) {
            dTmp = dSet;
            dSet = malloc(k);
            dSet->divisor = i;
            dTmp->next = dSet;
        }
    }

    dSet->next = 0;

    return (dBase);
}

//  frees allocated memory
void releaseMem(struct divisorSet *dSet) {
    struct divisorSet *dTmp;

    while (dSet->next) {
        dTmp = dSet->next;
        free(dSet);
        dSet = dTmp;
    }

    free(dSet);
    return;
}

//  test if pythagorean triangle or not
int isRightTriangle(int a, int b, int c) {
    struct divisorSet *dSet, *dTmp, *dBase;
    int g, baseA, baseB, baseC, m, n;

    g = gcd(a, gcd(b, c));
    baseA = a / g;
    baseB = b / g;
    baseC = c / g;

    if (sort(&baseA, &baseB, &baseC)) return (0);

    dSet = createDivisorSet(baseB / 2);
    dBase = dSet;

    while (dSet->next) {
        n = dSet->divisor * dSet->divisor;
        dTmp = dSet;

        while (dTmp->next) {
            dTmp = dTmp->next;
            m = dTmp->divisor * dTmp->divisor;

            if (m - n == baseA && m + n == baseC) {
                releaseMem(dBase);
                return (1);
            }
        }

        dSet = dSet->next;
    }

    releaseMem(dBase);
    return (0);
}

void scaleSides(int *a, int *b, int *c, int s) {
    *a *= s;
    *b *= s;
    *c *= s;
    return;
}

int main(void) {
    int a, b, c, s;

    s = 7040900;

    a = 160;
    b = 231;
    c = 281; // (right triangle)
    printf("a = %10d   b = %10d   c = %10d   rightTriangle = %d\n", a, b, c, isRightTriangle(a, b, c));

    scaleSides(&a, &b, &c, s); // testing for overflow (right triangle)
    printf("a = %10d   b = %10d   c = %10d   rightTriangle = %d\n", a, b, c, isRightTriangle(a, b, c));

    b += 2; // testing for overflow (not right triangle)
    printf("a = %10d   b = %10d   c = %10d   rightTriangle = %d\n", a, b, c, isRightTriangle(a, b, c));

    a = 207;
    b = 224;
    c = 305; // (right triangle)
    printf("a = %10d   b = %10d   c = %10d   rightTriangle = %d\n", a, b, c, isRightTriangle(a, b, c));

    scaleSides(&a, &b, &c, s); // testing for overflow (right triangle)
    printf("a = %10d   b = %10d   c = %10d   rightTriangle = %d\n", a, b, c, isRightTriangle(a, b, c));

    b += 2; // testing for overflow (not right triangle)
    printf("a = %10d   b = %10d   c = %10d   rightTriangle = %d\n", a, b, c, isRightTriangle(a, b, c));

    printf("press <enter> to exit...\n");
    getchar();
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: Your second formula is wrong, it should be `b = 2 * m * n;`. For example, for the most basic right triangle, a=3, b=4, c=5, you have m=2 and n=1.

Comment: Have to divide all 3 numbers by their GCD first

Answer (score 1):

You can increase the range of values that can be handled by means of extended arithmetic.

If you split the number `X` in two parts of at most `b` bits, you get `X = B X' + X"`, where `X'` and `X"` have at most `b` bits (`B` is the `b`'th power of `2`). Then squaring, `X² = B²X'² + 2BX'X" + X"²`, where the three parts have at most `b+1` significand bits.

If you decompose the products in parts of `b` bits, you rewrite as

```
B²(B [X'²]' + [X'²]") + 2B(B [X'X"]' + [X'X"]") + B[X"²]' + [X"²]"
```

and get

```
B³ [X'²]' + B² ([X'²]" + 2[X'X"]') + B (2[X'X"]" + [X"²]') + [X"²]"
```

With some care, keeping a few guard bits and handling the carries, you can obtain the result arranged in two words.

Extended addition is straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

Before anything else, let's assume the value of all the legs are positive integers. They must verify the elementary triangle relationships:

- `0 < a`, `0 < b`, `0 < c`;
- `a < b + c`, `b < c + a`, `c < a + b`;
- `abs(a - b) < c`, `abs(b - c) < a`, `abs(c - a) < b`.

Otherwise they cannot be the legs of a triangle.

#### A solution that refines the solution proposed by @mohit-jain:

1. Let the legs be `a` > `b` > `c`. The [Pythagorean theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem) says that if `a * a = b * b + c * c` then `a`, `b` and `c` are the legs of a right triangle (`a` being the hypotenuse).
   The equation can be rewritten as `a * a - c * c = b * b`, or `(a + c) * (a - c) = b * b`;
2. Assign `sum = a + c`, `diff = a - c`. **This is where the algorithm can overflow (`a + c`)**.
3. Now `b * b = sum * diff`. If `sum` and `diff` are not [mutually prime integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coprime_integers) then their [GCD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor) must also divide `b`. Compute `GCD(sum, diff)` and check if it divides `b`. If it doesn't divide `b` then it is not a square triangle.
4. Divide `sum`, `diff` and `b` by `GCD(sum, diff)`. If the original triangle is a right triangle, the equation `b * b = sum * diff` still stands (and vice-versa).
5. Now `sum` and `diff` don't have any common factors. If the equation is verified then `sum` and `b` (and also `diff` and `b`) must have common factors. Let `b1` = `b2` = `b`. The equation is `b1 * b2 = sum * diff`.
6. Divide `b1` and `sum` by their GCD; divide `b1` and `diff` by their GCD.
7. Divide `b2` and `sum` by their GCD; divide `b2` and `diff` by their GCD.
8. Now the values of `b1`, `b2`, `sum` and `diff` are smaller but it's possible that they are still too large. However, because of the divisions in the previous steps, `b1` and `b2` doesn't share factors with `sum` and `diff`. The only case they verify the equation is when `b1 == b2 == sum == diff == 1`.

The code is pretty lengthy. You can find it in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/axiac/e481166299a449f34f4959c82d9c3623). It doesn't verify the basic conditions for the numbers to be the legs of a triangle (exposed above) but implements the algorithm and uses the remark #2 (below) to avoid overflows.

---

#### Remark #1

Another possibility is to check if the legs verify some [elementary properties of Pythagorean triangles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple#Elementary_properties_of_primitive_Pythagorean_triples). Most of these checks use only simple mathematical operations and can reject many leg combinations. For the ones that pass, use the algorithm above.

#### Remark #2

The mathematical properties in the Wikipedia page listed above can also be used to find common factors for the legs or convenient ways to combine them in order to find their common factors and reduce them.

For example, if all the legs are even numbers then they can be divided by `2` before anything else. The operation can be repeated while all of them are still even.
After that, if the hypotenuse is still an even number then they cannot be the legs of a right triangle (see the properties in the list)

Given the hypotenuse is `a` in the algorithm above, the other odd number can be chosen to be `c` (instead of the smallest number). This approach guarantees that `sum` and `diff` are even numbers and `sum` can be divided by `2` without actually computing `a + c`.

When `a` and `c` are odd, `sum / 2` can be computed as `a / 2 + c / 2 + 1`. This completely removes the risk of overflow and the rest of the algorithm turns all the involved numbers smaller and smaller on each step.

Comment: It is possible to avoid overflow at step 2 if you craft a special version of `gcd`.

Answer (score 0):

If a^2+b^2=c^2 (modulo p_i) for some primes p1, p2, ..., then you know that a^2+b^2=c^2 (modulo p1*p2*...). By picking primes so that the intermediate sums don't overflow, you can check an arbitrary range.

Here's code that works for c^2 up to 1e22, which means it's valid for a, b, c all 32 bit ints. If that's not sufficient, you can use more bases (or larger primes, being careful to make sure that the intermediate calculations don't overflow your ints).

```
void swap(int *a, int *b) {
    int t = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = t;
}

int bases[] = {5051, 5059, 5077, 5081, 5087, 5099};

int is_rightangled(int a, int b, int c) {
  if (a > c) swap(&a, &c);
  if (b > c) swap(&b, &c);
  for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(bases)/sizeof(bases[0]); i++) {
    int p = bases[i];
    int ap = a % p, bp = b % p, cp = c % p;
    if (((ap * ap) + (bp * bp)) % p != (cp * cp) % p) return 0;
  }
  return 1;
}
```